# Significance of '&' Symbol in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, wsdl

I am currently working on a form that posts data to SAP. I am using JavaScript to invoke a Web Service to do this. I am running into an issue where one of the fields in the form has the value of 'GT&N' and I only get an error when the '&' symbol is present. I have looked on Google but have found nothing in relation the the & Symbol and JavaScript.

**Error Message I'm receiving from the Web Page:**

Unexpected end of file. Following elements are not closed: Characteristic_Value, RunParameter, Run, Body, Envelope. Line 1, position 2520

**The 'Characteristic_Value' is my field within the form.

**Error I see when I debug:**

[image: See Screen Shot]

Whenever I do not use the '&' Symbol, everything works great. I also tried using other special charecters and it posts just fine.

There is quite a bit of code to this so I am not going to post all of it unless requested as this is just a general question in regards to the '&' Symbol and JavaScript.

**The JavaScript Code**

```
//Create
var WebServer = "http://webserver";
var WebServiceName = "CreateIngredient";
var ScriptType = "Transaction";
var RepeatingTableXMLPath = "/my:myFields/my:CreateIngredient/my:CreateIngredient_Repeat";

// To Call Web service from infopath
function CreateIngredient(theXmlNode) {

//Add parameter into the request
var addBatchRequest = new SOAPClientParameters();
var Addresses = new Array();
var AddressXmlNodes = theXmlNode.selectNodes(RepeatingTableXMLPath);
// Loop for Input Field from Repeating Table
for (var i = 0; i < AddressXmlNodes.length; i++) {
    var xPath = AddressXmlNodes[i].getXPath();
    // Input field, It can be n number of fields
    addBatchRequest.add("Material_description", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Material_description").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Base_Unit_of_Measure", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Base_Unit_of_Measure").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Material_group", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Material_group").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("External_Material_Group", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:External_Material_Group").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Division", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Division").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Authorization_Group", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Authorization_Group").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Gross_weight", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Gross_weight").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Weight_Unit", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Weight_Unit").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Net_weight", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Net_weight").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Dangerous_Goods_Indicator_Profile", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Dangerous_Goods_Indicator_Profile").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Class_number", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Class_number").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Characteristic_Value", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Characteristic_Value").getValue().toString());
    addBatchRequest.add("Class_number1", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Class_number1").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Plant", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Plant").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Checking_Group_for_Availability_Check", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Checking_Group_for_Availability_Check").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Batch_management_requirement_indicator", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Batch_management_requirement_indicator").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Transportation_group", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Transportation_group").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Loading_group", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Loading_group").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Profit_Center", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Profit_Center").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Purchasing_group", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Purchasing_group").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Plant-Specific_Material_Status", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Plant-Specific_Material_Status").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Tax_indicator_for_material__Purchasing_", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Tax_indicator_for_material__Purchasing_").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Indicator___automatic_purchase_order_allowed_", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Indicator___automatic_purchase_order_allowed_").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Purchasing_Value_Key", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Purchasing_Value_Key").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Storage_location", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Storage_location").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Temperature_conditions_indicator", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Temperature_conditions_indicator").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Label_type", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Label_type").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Label_form", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Label_form").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Minimum_remaining_shelf_life", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Minimum_remaining_shelf_life").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Total_shelf_life", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Total_shelf_life").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Storage_percentage", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Storage_percentage").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Documentation_required_indicator", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Documentation_required_indicator").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("QM_in_Procurement_is_Active", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:QM_in_Procurement_is_Active").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Control_Key_for_Quality_Management_in_Procurement", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Control_Key_for_Quality_Management_in_Procurement").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Valuation_Class", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Valuation_Class").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Price_control_indicator", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Price_control_indicator").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Price_unit", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Price_unit").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Standard_price", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Standard_price").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Price_unit_for_valuation_prices_based_on_tax_commercial_law", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Price_unit_for_valuation_prices_based_on_tax_commercial_law").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Material-related_origin", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Material-related_origin").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Variance_Key", AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Variance_Key").getValue());
    addBatchRequest.add("Lot_Size_for_Product_Costing",     AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:Lot_Size_for_Product_Costing").getValue());




    // Output field has been field with text Retrieving... in Gray color for presentation purpose only
    var LogFieldNode = AddressXmlNodes[i].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:LogField");
    var txtLog = document.getElementById("SV_" + LogFieldNode.getAttribute("SVFormElementId"));
    txtLog.value = "Retrieving...";
    txtLog.style.color = 'Gray';


    // Final web service call parameter
    var pl = new SOAPClientParameters();
    pl.add("RunParameter", addBatchRequest.toXml());
    pl.toXml();
    SOAPClient.invoke(WebServer + "/formsservice.svc/basic", "Run", pl, true,    CreateIngredient_callBack, i);
}
}

// To display the retrieved result in the proper output fields
function CreateIngredient_callBack(u, xmlresponse, RowNumber) {
var theXmlNode1 = SVFormInternalGetProperXmlNode(SVForms[0]);

var AddressXmlNodes1 = theXmlNode1.selectNodes(RepeatingTableXMLPath);
var xPath = AddressXmlNodes1[RowNumber].getXPath();

var LogFieldNode = AddressXmlNodes1[RowNumber].selectSingleNode(xPath + "/my:LogField");
var txtLog = document.getElementById("SV_" + LogFieldNode.getAttribute("SVFormElementId"));
txtLog.style.color = "";
txtLog.value = "";

if (u == null)
    alert("No data retrieved for Row Number " + (RowNumber + 1) + ".");
else {
    //Display result in repeating table

    if (u.LogField) {
        LogFieldNode.setValue(u.LogField);
        document.getElementById("SV_" +  LogFieldNode.getAttribute("SVFormElementId")).value = u.LogField;
    }

}
}


///////////////////// Do not modify below this line ///////////////////////////////

var WsdlResult = null;
//Helping method: To build xml
 function SOAPClientParameters() {
var _pl = new Array();
this.add = function (name, value) {
    _pl[name] = value;
    return _pl;
}

this.toXml = function () {
    var xml = "";
    for (var p in _pl) {
        if (typeof (_pl[p]) != "function")
            xml += "<" + p + ">" + _pl[p].toString() + "</" + p + ">";
    }
    return xml;
}
}

function SOAPClientRepeatingParametersXml(name, values) {
var xml = "";
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

    xml += "<" + name + ">" + values[i].toString() + "</" + name + ">";

}
return xml;
}

function SOAPClient() { }

SOAPClient.invoke = function (url, method, parameters, async, callback, RowNumber) {
if (async)
    SOAPClient._loadWsdl(url, method, parameters, async, callback, RowNumber);
else
    return SOAPClient._loadWsdl(url, method, parameters, async, callback, RowNumber);
}

// private: wsdl cache
SOAPClient_cacheWsdl = new Array();

// private: invoke async
SOAPClient._loadWsdl = function (url, method, parameters, async, callback, RowNumber) {
// load from cache?
var wsdl = SOAPClient_cacheWsdl[url];

if (wsdl + "" != "" && wsdl + "" != "undefined")
    return SOAPClient._sendSoapRequest(url, method, parameters, async, callback, wsdl, RowNumber);
// get wsdl
var xmlHttp = SOAPClient._getXmlHttp();
xmlHttp.open("GET", url + "?wsdl", async);
if (async) {
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
            SOAPClient._onLoadWsdl(url, method, parameters, async, callback, xmlHttp, RowNumber);
    }
}
xmlHttp.send(null);
if (!async)
    return SOAPClient._onLoadWsdl(url, method, parameters, async, callback, xmlHttp, RowNumber);
}

SOAPClient._onLoadWsdl = function (url, method, parameters, async, callback, req, RowNumber) {
var wsdl = req.responseXML;
SOAPClient_cacheWsdl[url] = wsdl; // save a copy in cache
return SOAPClient._sendSoapRequest(url, method, parameters, async, callback, wsdl, RowNumber);
}

SOAPClient._sendSoapRequest = function (url, method, parameters, async, callback, wsdl, RowNumber) {
// get namespace
try {
    var ns = "http://servername.com/server/";
    // build SOAP request
    var sr =
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
            "<soap:Envelope " +
            "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" " +
            'xmlns:api="http://IPAddress/Integrics/Enswitch/API" ' +
            "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" " +
            "xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
            "<soap:Body>" +
            "<" + method + " xmlns=\"" + ns + "\">" +
            parameters.toXml() +
            "</" + method + "></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
    // send request
    var xmlHttp = SOAPClient._getXmlHttp();
    xmlHttp.open("POST", url, async);
    var soapaction = ((ns.lastIndexOf("/") != ns.length - 1) ? ns + "/" : ns) + method;
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://servername.com/server/I" + ScriptType + "Service/Process(" + WebServiceName + ")");
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    if (async) {
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
                SOAPClient._onSendSoapRequest(method, async, callback, wsdl, xmlHttp, RowNumber);
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.send(sr);
}
catch (ex) { }
if (!async)
    return SOAPClient._onSendSoapRequest(method, async, callback, wsdl, xmlHttp, RowNumber);
}

SOAPClient._onSendSoapRequest = function (method, async, callback, wsdl, req, RowNumber) {
var o = null;
var nd = SOAPClient._getElementsByTagName(req.responseXML, method + "Result");
if (nd.length == 0) {
    if (req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("faultcode").length > 0);
    alert(req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("faultstring")  [0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
else
    o = SOAPClient._soapresult2object(nd[0], wsdl);
if (callback)
    callback(o, req.responseXML, RowNumber);
if (!async)
    return o;
}

// private: utils
SOAPClient._getElementsByTagName = function (document, tagName) {
try {
    // trying to get node omitting any namespaces (latest versions of  MSXML.XMLDocument)
    return document.selectNodes(".//*[local-name()=\"" + tagName + "\"]");
}
catch (ex) { }
// old XML parser support
return document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
}

SOAPClient._soapresult2object = function (node, wsdl) {
return SOAPClient._node2object(node, wsdl);
}
SOAPClient._node2object = function (node, wsdl) {
// null node
if (node == null)
    return null;
// text node
if (node.nodeType == 3 || node.nodeType == 4)
    return SOAPClient._extractValue(node, wsdl);
// leaf node
if (node.childNodes.length == 1 && (node.childNodes[0].nodeType == 3 ||  node.childNodes[0].nodeType == 4))
    return SOAPClient._node2object(node.childNodes[0], wsdl);
var isarray = SOAPClient._getTypeFromWsdl(node.nodeName,  wsdl).toLowerCase().indexOf("arrayof") != -1;
// object node
if (!isarray) {
    var obj = null;
    if (node.hasChildNodes())
        obj = new Object();
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var p = SOAPClient._node2object(node.childNodes[i], wsdl);
        obj[node.childNodes[i].nodeName] = p;
    }
    return obj;
}
// list node
else {
    // create node ref
    var l = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++)
        l[l.length] = SOAPClient._node2object(node.childNodes[i], wsdl);
    return l;
}
return null;
}
SOAPClient._extractValue = function (node, wsdl) {
var value = node.nodeValue;
switch (SOAPClient._getTypeFromWsdl(node.parentNode.nodeName, wsdl).toLowerCase()) {
    default:
    case "s:string":
        return (value != null) ? value + "" : "";
    case "s:boolean":
        return value + "" == "true";
    case "s:int":
    case "s:long":
        return (value != null) ? parseInt(value + "", 10) : 0;
    case "s:double":
        return (value != null) ? parseFloat(value + "") : 0;
    case "s:datetime":
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        else {
            value = value + "";
            value = value.substring(0, value.lastIndexOf("."));
            value = value.replace(/T/gi, " ");
            value = value.replace(/-/gi, "/");
            var d = new Date();
            d.setTime(Date.parse(value));
            return d;
        }
}
}
SOAPClient._getTypeFromWsdl = function (elementname, wsdl) {
var ell = wsdl.getElementsByTagName("s:element"); // IE
if (ell.length == 0)
    ell = wsdl.getElementsByTagName("element"); // MOZ
for (var i = 0; i < ell.length; i++) {
    if (ell[i].attributes["name"] + "" == "undefined")  // IE
    {
        if (ell[i].attributes.getNamedItem("name") != null && ell[i].attributes.getNamedItem("name").nodeValue == elementname &&  ell[i].attributes.getNamedItem("type") != null)
            return ell[i].attributes.getNamedItem("type").nodeValue;
    }
    else // MOZ
    {
        if (ell[i].attributes["name"] != null && ell[i].attributes["name"].value ==  elementname && ell[i].attributes["type"] != null)
            return ell[i].attributes["type"].value;
    }
}
return "";
}

// private: xmlhttp factory
SOAPClient._getXmlHttp = function () {
try {
    if (window.XDomainRequest) {
        var req = new window.XDomainRequest();
        if (req.readyState == null) {
            req.readyState = 1;
            req.addEventListener("load",
                                function () {
                                    req.readyState  = 4;
                                    if (typeof req.onreadystatechange == "function")
                                        req.onreadystatechange();
                                },
                                false);
        }
        return req;
    }
}
catch (ex) {
    try {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            // some versions of Moz do not support the readyState property and the  onreadystate event so we patch it!
            if (req.readyState == null) {
                req.readyState = 1;
                req.addEventListener("load",
                                function () {
                                    req.readyState  = 4;
                                    if (typeof  req.onreadystatechange == "function")
                                         req.onreadystatechange();
                                },
                                false);
            }
            return req;
        }

    }

    catch (ex) {
        try {
            // Internet Explorer
            if (window.ActiveXObject)
                return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");     //ActiveXObject(SOAPClient._getXmlHttpProgID());
        } catch (e) {
            // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
            try {

                return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {
                    alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
}


SOAPClient._getXmlHttpProgID = function () {
if (SOAPClient._getXmlHttpProgID.progid)
    return SOAPClient._getXmlHttpProgID.progid;
var progids = ["Msxml2.XMLHTTP.5.0", "Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0", "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0",  "MSXML2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"];
var o;
for (var i = 0; i < progids.length; i++) {
    try {
        o = new ActiveXObject(progids[i]);
        return SOAPClient._getXmlHttpProgID.progid = progids[i];
    }
    catch (ex) { };
}
throw new Error("Could not find an installed XML parser");
}
```

Thanks in advance for any helpful input.

Cheers

[image: The Code (I have also tried without the <code>toString()</code> function)]
[image: The Web Service XML]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Inside a string, it has no special meaning to JavaScript. In HTML, it can represent the beginning of a HTML entity, which is a sequence of characters to represent a special character.

Comment: Any chance we can see the rest of the JS? Are you triggering an `alert()` anywhere?

Comment: Yea, I'll upload everything now. I am using an `alert()` for the error messages but nothing else.

Comment: The ampersand has special meaning in XML and should be escaped. Could it be getting caught up in SOAPClient?

Comment: That's a good thought. I would expect that to be something to look into. I just posted the code...how would I escape it?

Comment: @frankbilly You can escape it with &amp; - the ampersand tells the XML parser that the following characters make up an escape sequence.

Comment: If you are using a string that is put into XML or XHTML then you should use `&amp;`.

Comment: Interesting. When I enter the value '&amp;' into the text box and run it, it works...

Comment: Is there an easy way to tell the XML to ignore '&' symbols? I know that's a longshot...

Comment: @frankbilly I don't know of a way to ignore them, but you can alternatively wrap the data in `<![CDATA[GT&N]]>`. The parser should interpret it as `GT&amp;N`.

Comment: Will that infect data integrity though? Meaning that if I need that '&' symbol to be present in the Database, will it still show up? Or will it deliver GT&amp;N?

Comment: I'm almost certain the integrity is retained, but am looking for a source to confirm. I'll post anything I find that can answer either way.

Comment: The consensus seems to be that it's the web service's responsibility to convert the data back to its original form. Do you have access to the web service code? If it's using a halfway decent XML parser to read the values before storing in the database, there shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try &#38 instead of & sign.